# Создание модального диалогового окна поверх окна родителя

Tags: c++, qt

Не могу не где найти пример как это сделать.
Нужно создать модальное окно поверх окна родителя вывести там информацию и закрыть через 5 секунд или по сигналу из второго потока. 
Версия qt4.7.8.

Comment: Для того знания нужны, а не примеры. Почитайте http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.6.x/index.html

Comment: Думаю пример тоже поможет.

Comment: принцип такой - запускаешь таймер на 5 сек. в конструкторе этого же класса диалога (`startTimer` или `singleShot`)  и ловишь в `timerEvent` или в слоте, к которому приконектил сигнал таймера

Comment: Это я понимаю. Мне не ясно как создать модальное окно.По верх окна родителя.

Answer (score 0):

Все довольно просто, чтобы создать модальное окно нужно просто при создании этого окна передать ссылку на родителя и использовать функцию setWindowModality(), вот пример:

```
ModalWindow pModalWindow = new ModalWindow(this); // передали основное окно через this
pModalWindow->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::WindowModal); // сказали что это окно будет модальным и будет блокировать доступ к родителю
pModalWindow->show();
```

Если вам нужен таймер, то у Qt есть свои таймеры, называются QTimer.
В *.h файле модального окна сделайте предварительное декларирование этого класса так:

```
...начало .h файла...
class QTimer;
...
class ModalWindow : public QMainWindow
...
```

Теперь, создайте ссылку на этот объект в этом же файле так:

```
...
private:
QTimer* pTimer;
...
```

После этого вам нужно создать функцию-слот, которая будет вызвана при завершении таймера, создадим ее в этом же файле так:

```
private slots:
void slotTimerTimeout();
```

В конструкторе ModalWindow (в *.cpp файле) создайте объект таймера:

```
pTimer = new QTimer();
pTimer ->setInterval(5000); // 5000 миллисекунд == 5 секунд
connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ModalWindow::slotTimerTimeout);
pTimer ->start();
```

Теперь не забудьте добавить в деструктор очистку:

```
delete pTimer;
```

и создать реализацию нашего слота:

```
void ModalWindow::slotTimerTimeout()
{
pTimer->stop(); // остановим таймер, он больше не нужен

close(); // закрыть это окно
}
```

Так, если вы не храните ссылку на модальное окно в *.h файле основного (родительского окна), то вам еще нужно в модальном окне переопределить защищенный (protected) метод закрытия:

```
void closeEvent    (QCloseEvent *event);
```

и написать в нем это:

```
Q_UNUSED(event) // не используем переменную event

deleteLater(); // окно поставится на удаление
```

А если храните ссылку на него в *.h родителя, то нужно отправить сигнал родителю.
Вот и собственно все.